# Slide up multiple <ul> elements using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to construct a jquery statement that will slideUp() all `<ul>` elements whose siblings don't contain a set of specific classes (.clicked, .chosen).

Suppose I have the following nested `<ul>` structure:

```
<ul class="mainmenu">
    <li>Dogs</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Fido</li>
        <li class="chosen">Barney</li>
        <li>Turbo</li>
    </ul>
    <li>Cats</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Sylvester</li>
        <li>Felix</li>
        <li>Garfield</li>
    </ul>
    <li class="clicked">Hamsters</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Chubbs</li>
        <li>Oreo</li>
        <li>Ruby</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

For the above example, I would like to slideUp() only the 'Cats' `<ul>` element ('Sylvester', 'Felix', 'Garfield') because none of it's elements use the 'chosen' or 'clicked' classes.

My current jquery statement reads:

```
$('.mainmenu').first().siblings().not('.clicked, .chosen').slideUp();
```

This, and everything else I have tried, returns nothing.  Suggestions?

Comment: As a note, as this is also going to affect the selectors in JavaScript: The way you nest the `ul`s is invalid. A nested `ul` should be a child of an `li` and not a sibling of it.

Comment: @mrtedweb check my answer to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You HTML looks challenging :) but somehow, I've managed to create a query to perform what you're looking for.

And if you want to check multiple class for particular element you can use [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) as well.

```js
//Check li doesn't have clicked class and then filter ul next to the li 
$('.mainmenu > li').not('.clicked').next('ul').filter(function(){
  //Find the ul, if it's any of li doesn't have chosen class 
  if(!$(this).find('li').hasClass('chosen'))
  {
    return $(this);
  }
}).slideUp();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="mainmenu">
    <li>Dogs</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Fido</li>
        <li class="chosen">Barney</li>
        <li>Turbo</li>
    </ul>
    <li>Cats</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Sylvester</li>
        <li>Felix</li>
        <li>Garfield</li>
    </ul>
    <li class="clicked">Hamsters</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Chubbs</li>
        <li>Oreo</li>
        <li>Ruby</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: Guess the quote is misplaced. It has to be `$('.mainmenu').find('li:eq(1)').slideUp();` :-)